# Netbeans and creating JUnit tests

Tags: netbeans, junit

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 with a web project that I have imported from existing sources. I have added the JUnit library to my project. In Netbeans tutorials online for version < 7 it says to create a JUnit test for a given existing class by righ-clicking on the source file in the project, select the menu "Tools" and then there should be an option to create a JUnit test. However this option does not appear for me. There seem to bean old bug report/request for functionality, describing this but it does not seem to have been resolved as it is mentioned as late as 2011-05-09 on the Netbeans bugzilla list (link [Related on bugzilla](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69390)). On the bugzilla it is suggested to explicitly create the folder `/test/unit/src` in the project, but still after this when I try to create JUnit test for an existing class from rightclick project -> new -> other -> JUnit, I get "no tests root folder was found in the selected project" (I tried changing the foldername to tests as well). Can I explicitly set this location in some configuration file and is there any way of getting the expected functionality allowing me to simply righclick a source file and select "JUnit test" to create a JUnit stub for the selected class ?

Comment: I reimported the project *making sure* to create a test folder when being guided by the project wizard, and things now work as expected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you right click on the project and pick "Properties" you should see "Sources" on the left.  Select that and then click "Add Folder..." under the "Test Package Folders" section.  This will add a new test directory.  If you have an existing one, delete it first (just make sure the test sources are saved somewhere else) and then add the new one.

Answer (score 4):

If you right click on your project and add new **Unit Tests-> JUnit Test** it will automatically create the path for you.

Comment: When I tried this I got an error that "No tests root folder was found in the selected project."

Answer (score 1):

if src/main/java is missing, netbeans 8 does not let you create test case in src/test/java using the wizard

looks like a bug, still valid in 2015

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project you've made has a large effect on whether there's a test root already or no.  In Netbeans 7.1.1, a "POM Project" doesn't create a test root directory as a part of the project build process.  However, making a Java Application did make a test root by default.

I tried the directions offered by mamboking and I wasn't able to change the directories in the Sources section of the project properties.  Making a new project of type "Java Application" make the correct test root.